# How do I configure accessToken lifetime in ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API using new IdentityApi endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0, asp.net-minimal-apis

I've just started working on a new ASP.NET Core 8 Minimal API. I'm trying to play with some new features regarding identity.

I'm using the class below to register auth services.

```
internal static class AuthInstaller
{
    internal static IServiceCollection InstallAuth(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Then in my endpoints installer class, I'm invoking `MapIdentityApi` to map identity endpoints as follows.

```
...
groupBuilder.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();
...
```

I have it all working, but the accessToken lifetime is set to 3600 seconds. I've spent much time trying to figure out on how to configure that lifetime. Is there a quick way to configure that without having to write custom bearer token creation logic?

I've looked through Microsoft documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: There are limitations to customize for now https://andrewlock.net/should-you-use-the-dotnet-8-identity-api-endpoints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code

```
...
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.ConfigureAll<BearerTokenOptions>(option => {
    option.BearerTokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
...
```